# How to query images and videos in cursorLoader without folders?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-cursorloader

**Question:**

I query images and videos as it has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664826/access-ordered-images-and-video-in-same-cursor).

```
String[] projection = {
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, 
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE};

String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
     + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE 
     + " OR "
     + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
     + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
this,
queryUri,
projection,
selection,
null, // Selection args (none).
MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
```

But there also return folders, for example `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/Sent`. How I can avoid this?

I need only images and videos, no folder paths.

**Solution:**

Add

> AND "+MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+" IS NOT NULL

into query.

Comment: I don't know how reliable it is, but glancing at the files table in the media DB it looks like you can just check if the mime_type column is not null

Comment: Does the "MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA" colums contain folder-only entries on your device? On my 3 android devices i only have entries with fullpath+filename like "/storage/sdcard0/dcim/camera/someFile.jpg" but no entries like " "/storage/sdcard0/dcim/camera"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, puting this " AND "+MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE+" IS NOT NULL" to SQL query helped : )